# Material picker always displays 1st of month from date assigned

Tags: angular, date, angular-material, momentjs

I am using a material datepicker and I am trying to set a value to it from the server.

this is the response: 21-07-2022

datepicker needs a date or a moment type so I am converting the response

```
this.form.controls['createdAt'].setValue(moment(data.createdAt, 'dd-MM-YYYY'));
```

`moment(data.createAt, 'dd-MM-YYYY')` works correctly, as I have a moment object with 21 July 2022.

The datepicker displays 1st July 2022.

I also tried to convert it to Date and momenttest variable is a Date with 1st July 2022.

```
const momenttest = moment(data.createdAt, 'dd-MM-YYYY').toDate();
 console.log(momenttest)
 this.serviceReviewForm.controls['createdAt'].setValue(momenttest);
```

How can I display the right date value?

Comment: you need give value to the `startAt` property of the calendar, see the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api#MatCalendar)

Comment: `dd` is the day of the week. `DD` is the date.

Comment: Beside the `dd` vs `DD` issue mentioned above - just to be sure, are you providing the correct date module (i.e. MatMomentDateModule)? I've seen people using moment without doing that way too many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this issue was replacing the dd with DD as:

```
this.form.controls['createdAt'].setValue(moment(data.createdAt, 'DD-MM-YYYY'));
```